# WP 7 click event of the Listbox Item cell

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I added items to the Listbox. Now I want to click on that each cell and move to the different pages.

How to identify selected cell in the List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with sender at your click event handler.

```
YourItemType _sender = sender as YourItemType;
```

Then, you can find out what item exactly it is. Do you have some unique field for your item? Use it.

```
if (_sender.uniqueValue == something)
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(...)
}
```

Comment: @Tharanga, actually, you didn't mentioned, what items exactly you have at your ListBox. The solutions can be different, I've written the most common one.